# Video card not working

Tags: graphics-card

I was running windows 7 and I was able to have 2 monitors. But I needed to reinstall my os and could not find 7 so I used vista. Now my video card only has 1 monitor - 2 does not show up or have an option to expand destop to another monitor. would this have to do with the OS?

The card is a  Matrox... it doesn't say on the card which model.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you need to go to [Matrox](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/drivers/), find the drivers for your graphics card, and install the version that is compatible with Vista.

This will likely allow you to use more than one monitor.

Alternatively, just run Windows Update, it may well have the official updated drivers for your graphics card already.  They usually have reasonable ones for AMD and Nvidia graphics cards.

Comment: You probably won't find a recent Matrox driver on Windows Update.